# Can Toph Beifong lavabend?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

She seems to be adept at bending most earth materials including mud and metal. Since Lava-bending is a subset of Earth bending, can she bend lava and could it possibly be because of how good she is at Earth-bending?

Answer (score 7):

No,  Toph has not been shown to lava bend in any media to date.

Comment: I'm saying whoud it be possibly

Comment: @Winterwolfsound As much fun as it would be to speculate, this site is geared toward definitive answers from the actual media.

Comment: @Winterwolfsound Toph is not one to be upstaged. If she could, she would have, then loudly bragged about it.

Comment: Given [that it is a subset of Earthbending](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Lavabending), she could *theoretically* do it. But, as CDE has said, she's never demonstrated or mentioned such abilities.

Comment: @phantom42 But then again, Metal bending is a more common subset of earthbending, but Bolin can't do it.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning, that she couldn't understand sand bending, preferring solid rock under her feet. Fluidy lava might also not suit her taste.

Comment: Notably, when Bolin mentions that he's a lavabender, she is genuinely impressed.  Toph doesn't tend to be impressed by people doing anything she considers "easy," (basically anything she can do herself), so its reasonable to assume she can't lavabend.  If she could, it would have been <crotchety old lady voice>"So what? Anyone can do that! Next you'll be bragging about tying your own shoes..."</crotchety old lady voice>

Comment: How can she invent metal bending but she can't lava bend. That makes me so sad cause toph Is bomb. She resembles me! A lot

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. When Toph is introduced in the Legend of Korra, her cooking setup might be lava-based.

[image]

[image]

The full scene can be watched [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvygidCkpUg). Notice how Korra's flame produces dynamic light, but whatever is under Toph's pot only produces a dim, constant light.

Comment: Never cooked on coals or embers, have you?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't strike me as a particularly good way of heating a large pot that isn't terribly close to the embers. There's also more glow and fewer ashen/charred parts than I'd expect in a bed of coals. It's hardly definitive evidence, (hence possibly and might be) but this being a casual use of lavabending doesn't seem like a completely unreasonable interpretation.